# Run program from relative path

Tags: powershell

I was trying to, from powershell, to make an executable to run another program like this:

```
PS> $env:userprofile\program.exe $env:userprofile\program2.exe
```

doing this I get

```
At line:1 char:17
+ $env:userprofile\program.exe $env:userprofile\program2.exe
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'program.exe' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

both programs are in the same folder

Is such thing possible?

Comment: try it like this `& "$env:userprofile\program.exe" "$env:userprofile\program2.exe"`

Comment: Wouldn't program.exe have to be installed in the UserProfile folder? Rather than in C:\Program Files, etc.?

Comment: @RetiredGeek In this case not necessarily

Comment: In short: An executable path that is _quoted_ or contains _variable references_ must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); see the linked duplicate for details.